# Getting an Error msg while using IF condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am using IF condition but is given me compile error "Else without IF"
    I want to right loop statement, so it will calculate formula till display cells

```
With Range("K3:K" & LR)
LR = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(2, 0)


If Range("K" & LR).Value = "No" Then
With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(2, 0)
With Range("L3:L" & LR)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L3" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = ""

ElseIf Range("K" & LR).Value = "Yes" Then

With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(2, 0)
With Range("L3:L" & LR)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L3" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*0.25%"

Else

Return




End With
 End With
  End If
   End With
    End With
```

Please can you help on this

Comment: With 4 nested `With` blocks I would highly recommend proper indentation. You will notice that the `ElseIf` is indeed without `If` in the `With Range("L3:L" & LR)` block.

Comment: I count 6 `With` and 4 `End With`, so that points to a problem right there...  Also there's no `Return` in VBA, unless that's a method you've created.

Comment: I have added 2 End With and Else  Return, however still it is giving same error message

Comment: You can't have interleaving blocks of `With... End With` and `If ... End If`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't interleave blocks.

Following code will generate a `End If without If block` error:

```
If True Then
    With Range("A1")
End If
    End With
```

Following code will generate a `End With without With block` error:

```
With Range("A1")
    If True Then
End With
    End If
```

Use code like this:

```
With Range("A1")
    If True Then
    End If
End With
```

or

```
If True Then
    With Range("A1")
    End With
End If
```

As mentioned by arcadeprecinc, a proper indentitation of your code would have shown the problem.